# AZDelivery Serial Adapter FT232RL and ESP32 board

Tags: esp32, ftdi

I've just purchased an AZDelivery Serial Adapter FT232RL from USB to TTL to program an ESP-WROOM-32 board.

[image]

I'm very confused about which connections are needed.
Actually, I've connected TX2 (*on ESP32 board*) to RXI (*on FT232RL*), RX2 (*on ESP32 board*) to TX (*on FT232RL*), and GND to GND.

I'm powering the ESP32 with 3.3 V and set the power select jumper to 3.3 V on the FTDI serial adapter.

But, when I try to program the ESP32 by means Arduino IDE, I receive this error:

> A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header

Where am I wrong? Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The IDE likely expects there to be some circuitry that enables the IDE to put the ESP32 into programming mode.

That's usually done via the handshake pins. TX and RX only allow communication between the devices.

Comment: You can tie GPIO0 to 0V and power up the module. This should put it in bootloader mode. Once loaded, remove the wire from GPIO0 and your code should run. Refer to the esp devkit c schematics to see the circuitry to automate this process.

Comment: Hi Kartman. Thanks for your reply. I can't find GPIO0 on my ESP32 board. Any idea ?

Comment: Neither can I. If I Google esp wroom 32 i either get a module or a board which already has the usb serial interface. If it is the module, thrn it is labelled IO0. Or refer to the documentation to identify the actual pin.

Comment: Why are you connecting to tx2/rx2? The esp32 bootloader only supports uart0.

Comment: Hi Kartman. My module has its own USB serial interface. I'd like to add and external FT232 because I want power the board with an external power source and measure current consumption at different configurations (for study purpose) . I've don't well understood, among other things, which configuration must I set on the FT232 between: 3,3 or 5 V ? I've read, i.e., that settting 5V is dangerous for the ESP32. I'm very confused...